# Achieving top N results and 'Other' category in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the top 10 currencies (and their request count) from a table in an MySQL database and group all other currencies in an 'Other' category with request count equal to the sum of these currencies' request counts.

The below query gives me the correct result, but is probably highly inefficient.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT
  rank,
  CASE WHEN rank <=10 THEN ccy ELSE 'Other' END as ccy,
  SUM(req_count) AS requests
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN rank <= 10 THEN rank ELSE 11 END AS rank, ccy, req_count
  FROM (SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, ccy, req_count 
    FROM (SELECT have_currency AS ccy, COUNT(*) AS req_count
      FROM db1.table1
        GROUP BY have_currency
        ORDER BY req_count DESC)
      AS currencies)
    AS currencies)
  AS currencies
GROUP BY rank ASC;
```

Result:

```
# rank, ccy, requests
'1', 'SGD', '184481'
'2', 'USD', '10723'
'3', 'MYR', '8044'
'4', 'HKD', '7316'
'5', 'THB', '5725'
'6', 'JPY', '4930'
'7', 'INR', '2767'
'8', 'AUD', '2164'
'9', 'VND', '2130'
'10', 'CNY', '1965'
'11', 'Other', '10217'
```

Any way to make this more efficient?

Bonus question: is it possible to return the % of total for request counts instead of the absolute number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you looking for ?

```
SELECT rank, IF(rank>10,'other',ccy) AS ccy,sum(req_count)
FROM (
  SELECT @rank := (@rank := @rank+1) AS rank, ccy,req_count
  FROM (
    SELECT have_currency AS ccy, COUNT(*) AS req_count
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY have_currency
    ORDER BY req_count DESC
  ) AS d1
) AS d2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS param
GROUP BY LEAST(rank, 11);
```

Comment: @chrisvdb - if have change my answer. can you please try this

Comment: Still more complex than I would have imagined but it works!

Comment: Would you know how to make this query work nicely with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode? This is on by default in MySQL 5.7.